# Images are not coming in viewpager from SQLite in Android and in logcat show SqliteConstraint Exception

Tags: android

I want to insert many images in `viewpager` from sqlite, but these images are not showing in view pager and in logcat it shows error of SqliteConstraint exception.

However, the same code works for Gridview and in gridview images are coming properly, but not in view pager. This is the link which I refer http://androidsurya.blogspot.in/2014/01/multiple-images-insert-and-retrieve.html

This is the MainActivity

```
public class InsertandRetriveBlobData extends Activity
 {


    private DBhelper DbHelper;
    public static final String EMP_ID = "id";
    public static final String EMP_NAME = "name";
    public static final String EMP_AGE = "age";
    public static final String EMP_PHOTO = "photo";
    ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this,   employeeList);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        DbHelper = new DBhelper(this);

        Employee employee_One = new Employee(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), "Manish", 25);

        //Employee employee_Two = new Employee(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            //  getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), "Bondada", 26);

        DbHelper.open();
        // insert first employee one details
        DbHelper.insertEmpDetails(employee_One);
        // insert first employee two details
    //  DbHelper.insertEmpDetails(employee_Two);

        employeeList = DbHelper.retriveallEmpDetails();
        DbHelper.close();
    /*  GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, employeeList));*/

    }
}
```

This is the adapter ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{


    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    // Constructor
    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Employee> employeeList) {
        mContext = c;
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }



    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(employeeList.get(position).getBitmap());

        System.out.println("image showing according to position"+employeeList.get(position).getBitmap());

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return employeeList.size();
    }

}



public class DBhelper {



    public static final String EMP_ID = "id";
    public static final String EMP_NAME = "name";
    public static final String EMP_AGE = "age";
    public static final String EMP_PHOTO = "photo";

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EmployessDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String EMPLOYEES_TABLE = "Employees";

    private static final String CREATE_EMPLOYEES_TABLE = "create table "
            + EMPLOYEES_TABLE + " (" + EMP_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + EMP_PHOTO
            + " blob, " + EMP_NAME + " text, "
            + EMP_AGE + " integer );";

    private final Context mCtx;
    // create an empty array list with an initial capacity
    ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEES_TABLE);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EMPLOYEES_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public void Reset() {
        mDbHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1);
    }

    public DBhelper(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    }

    public DBhelper open() throws SQLException {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertEmpDetails(Employee employee) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(EMP_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(employee.getBitmap()));
        cv.put(EMP_NAME, employee.getName());
        cv.put(EMP_AGE, employee.getAge());
        mDb.insert(EMPLOYEES_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    // To get first employee details
    public Employee retriveEmpDetails() throws SQLException {
        Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, EMPLOYEES_TABLE, new String[] { EMP_PHOTO,
                EMP_NAME, EMP_AGE }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(EMP_PHOTO));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(EMP_NAME));
            int age = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(EMP_AGE));
            cur.close();
            return new Employee(Utility.getPhoto(blob), name, age);
        }

        cur.close();
        return null;
    }

    // To get list of employee details
    public ArrayList<Employee> retriveallEmpDetails() throws SQLException {
        Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, EMPLOYEES_TABLE, new String[] { EMP_PHOTO,
                EMP_NAME, EMP_AGE }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(EMP_PHOTO));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(EMP_NAME));
                int age = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(EMP_AGE));
                employeeList
                        .add(new Employee(Utility.getPhoto(blob), name, age));
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
        return employeeList;
    }
}




public class Employee {



    private Bitmap bmp;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Employee(Bitmap b, String n, int k) {
        bmp = b;
        name = n;
        age = k;
    }




    public Employee(String n, int k) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        name = n;
        age = k;
    }


    public Bitmap getBmp() {
        return bmp;
    }


    public void setBmp(Bitmap bmp) {
        this.bmp = bmp;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bmp;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}



public class Utility {


    // convert from bitmap to byte array
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    // convert from byte array to bitmap
    public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the full employee list at 
**employeeList = DbHelper.retriveallEmpDetails();**
You are not passing it to the viewpager adapter. What you passed on earlier was simply an empty arraylist. Gridview adapter works because you initialize it after the above line of code.

Comment: @Raghubanh Please edit in my code ...where i have to paas